# static mutable member variables in C++?

Tags: c++, static, member, mutable

why or for what reason is it not possible to declare a class member variable in C++ as `static mutable`? Something like

```
static mutable int t; //This won't compile
```

For me, there is no reason to ban such declarations. E.g. for reasons like maintaining a global class-wide statistics, it may be convenient to have static variable that can be altered by (logically) const methods. So either this is sort of a misdesign in C++ and unnecessarily complicated, or there is a practical or theoretical reason which I cannot see.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Non-const static members of the class can *already* be modified by any (const and non-const) methods of the class. There's no need and no point in declaring it with `mutable`. That would achieve absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The mutable keyword allows a "const" and therefore non-static member function to change non-static member variables marked as such (i.e., mutable). Static functions cannot be const and const member functions can change non-const static members. I know this is somewhat confusing, but it is because of this that there is no need to allow a mutable static member variable.